# How to disable urlencoding get-params in Refit?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, refit

I use Refit for RestAPI.
I need create query strings same `api/item?c[]=14&c[]=74`

In refit interface I created method

```
[Get("/item")]
Task<TendersResponse> GetTenders([AliasAs("c")]List<string> categories=null);
```

And create CustomParameterFormatter

```
string query = string.Join("&c[]=", values);
```

CustomParameterFormatter generated string `14&c[]=74`

But Refit encoded parameter and generated url `api/item?c%5B%5D=14%26c%5B%5D%3D74`

How disable this feature?

Answer (score 5):

First of all was your api server able to parse the follow?
`api/item?c%5B%5D=14%26c%5B%5D%3D74`

Encoding is great for avoiding code injection to your server.

This is something **Refit** is a bit opinionated about, i.e uris should be encoded, the server should be upgraded to read encoded uris.

But this clearly should be a opt-in settings in **Refit** but it´s not.

So you can currently can do that by using a DelegatingHandler:

```
/// <summary>
/// Makes sure the query string of an <see cref="System.Uri"/>
/// </summary>
public class UriQueryUnescapingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{   
    public UriQueryUnescapingHandler()
        : base(new HttpClientHandler()) { }
    public UriQueryUnescapingHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
        : base(innerHandler)
    { }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var uri = request.RequestUri;
        //You could also simply unescape the whole uri.OriginalString
        //but i don´t recommend that, i.e only fix what´s broken
        var unescapedQuery = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Query);

        var userInfo = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri.UserInfo) ? "" : $"{uri.UserInfo}@";
        var scheme = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri.Scheme) ? "" : $"{uri.Scheme}://";

        request.RequestUri = new Uri($"{scheme}{userInfo}{uri.Authority}{uri.AbsolutePath}{unescapedQuery}{uri.Fragment}");
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}


Refit.RestService.For<IYourService>(new HttpClient(new UriQueryUnescapingHandler()))
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who stumbles across this old question you can use  [[QueryUriFormat(UriFormat.Unescaped)]](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#unescape-querystring-parameters) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

‍♀️ In my case I had to some work on a legacy .NET 2.2 Core ASP app (i.e. couldn't use the [fancy attribute](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#unescape-querystring-parameters) mentioned in [mmoon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69253224/4636721).

To complete [Ahmed Alejo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40822267/4636721), and in particular if you're taking the ASP.NET Core DI container road, I've noticed that if I left the two ctors as they were in the original answer, the whole thing was kabooming (i.e. getting the infamous exception: `The 'DelegatingHandler' list is invalid because the property 'InnerHandler' of 'handler' is not null`).

So what I ended up doing was **to not write any ctors**, just as below

```cs
public class UriQueryUnescapingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var uri = request.RequestUri;
        var unescapedQuery = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Query);

        var userInfo = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri.UserInfo) ? string.Empty : $"{uri.UserInfo}@";
        var scheme = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri.Scheme) ? string.Empty : $"{uri.Scheme}://";

        request.RequestUri = new Uri($"{scheme}{userInfo}{uri.Authority}{uri.AbsolutePath}{unescapedQuery}{uri.Fragment}");
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

and then it just works like a charm when you're configuring the services that way :

```cs
services.AddTransient<UriQueryUnescapingHandler>();
// whatever other services you need to set up beforehand
services
    .AddRefitClient<IMyRefitService>(myRefitSettings)
    .ConfigureHttpClient(c =>
    {
        // whatever relevant HttpClient-related configuration action goes here
    })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<UriQueryUnescapingHandler>();
```